# JavaFX TableView - Generic OnEditCommit

Tags: java, generics, javafx

I would like to convert the following code to be of generic Java types to avoid having to manually re code the on edit commit for each new table column...

```
colOccurrences.setOnEditCommit(
            new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Damageloop, Float>>() {
                @Override 
                public void handle(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Damageloop, Float> t) {
                    ((Damageloop)t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                            t.getTablePosition().getRow())).setOccurrences(t.getNewValue());
                }
        });
```

I have tried adding the following code to a custom cell factory class which is assigned to each table column...

```
TableColumn<S, T> col = super.getTableColumn();
col.setOnEditCommit(
new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<S, T>>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(CellEditEvent<S, T> t) {
        TableColumn<S, T> col = t.getTableColumn();
        int row = t.getTablePosition().getRow();
        ObservableValue<T> ov = col.getCellObservableValue(row);
        if (ov instanceof WritableValue) {
            ((WritableValue<T>)ov).setValue(t.getNewValue());
        }
    }
});
```

And this successfully sets the underlying observable value of the cell being edited. However, when I call ...

```
TableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem()
```

In a further section of code the old unedited value is still returned. However, if I update my generic on edit commit to include the following...

```
TableColumn<S, T> col = super.getTableColumn();
col.setOnEditCommit(
new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<S, T>>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(CellEditEvent<S, T> t) {
        TableColumn<S, T> col = t.getTableColumn();
        int row = t.getTablePosition().getRow();
        ObservableValue<T> ov = col.getCellObservableValue(row);
        if (ov instanceof WritableValue) {
            ((WritableValue<T>)ov).setValue(t.getNewValue());
        }
        //NEW ADDITION TO EVENT HANDLER
        Date date;
        date = (Date) t.getNewValue();
        ((Damageloop) t.getTableView().getItems().get(t.getTablePosition().getRow())).setDamageloopworkshopduedate(date);
    }
});
```

The TableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() code will return the correct updated value.

Can anyone tell me why the oberservable value is not updating the backing list? or more appropriately how convert the new addition in my event handler to use generics?

Comment: Please post one of the properties including getter/setter/property getter form the `Damageloop` class and the `cellValueFactory` where this property is used...

Comment: Note your entire first block of code can simply be reduced to `colOccurrences.setOnEditCommit(t -> t.getRowValue().setOccurrences(t.getNewValue()));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, a couple of reasons you probably don't need this at all.

1. If you use the [JavaFX properties pattern](http://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=javase80&id=JFXBD107) in your model class, i.e. if you do

   ```
   public class Damageloop {

       private ObjectProperty<Float> occurrences = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(0.0f);

       public ObjectProperty<Float> occurrencesProperty() {
           return occurrences ;
       }

       public final Float getOccurrences() {
           return occurrencesProperty().get();
       }

       public final void setOccurrences(Float occurrences) {
           occurrencesProperty().set(occurrences);
       }

       // ...
   }
   ```

   then the standard editable table cells (such as `TextFieldTableCell`) will update the property on edit commit by default: i.e. there is no need to define an `onEditCommit` handler at all.
2. Even if you don't use the properties pattern as above, Java 8 lambda expressions and enhanced type inference already allow you to reduce your entire first code block to a one-line statement:

   ```
   colOccurrences.setOnEditCommit(e -> e.getRowValue().setOccurrences(e.getNewValue()));
   ```

If you really want to create this in a reusable generic way, you can do something like

```
public class TableUtils {

    public static <S,T> void createDefaultEditHandler(
        TableColumn<S,T> column, BiConsumer<S,T> committer) {

        column.setOnEditCommit(event -> 
            committer.accept(event.getRowValue(), event.getNewValue()));

    }
}
```

which you can invoke with:

```
TableUtils.createDefaultEditHandler(colOccurrences, Damageloop::setOccurrences);
```

(and this is completely reusable for columns of other types...).

Comment: Lots of good solutions for my issue here. Thanks for the comprehensive answer :).

Comment: Why `setOnEditCommit`? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html says "Unless you then handle the writeback to the property (or the relevant data source), nothing will happen." What kind of precautions do we need to take to make sure this is not our fate?

Comment: @LimitedAtonement isn't that exactly what I answered here? If you use the JavaFX properties pattern and don't call `setOnEditCommit`, the default value of `onEditCommit` will update the property.

Comment: Why didn't you recommend `addEventHandler` so that the default handler is still there?

Comment: @LimitedAtonement I must not be understanding you. If you are already in the situation where the default handler does what you want, you don't need a custom handler at all. If the default handler doesn't do what you want, what's the point in retaining it?

Comment: @James_D I'm wanting to add to the custom handler. I want the default handler to insert data into the data source, but I also want another column to be updated to a calculated value. I'm probably not understanding the original problem here, nor your solution, because I have my own problem :-)